Strategy Game with Two Players and Penny Removal - How to Determine the Winner?
I'm working on a strategy game involving two players, A and B, and I'd like to analyze the gameplay mechanics and strategies involved.
Game Setup:

There are two piles of pennies: the first pile contains 2 pennies, and the second pile contains 3 pennies.
Player A goes first and must remove at least one penny from one of the two piles.

Game Rules:

Players must remove at least one penny during their turn.
A player can only remove pennies from one pile at a time (they cannot take from both piles in a single turn).
Players can choose to remove any number of pennies from the selected pile, as long as it's at least one.
If at any point one of the piles is completely empty, the player who takes the last penny (or all pennies from the remaining pile) loses the game, making the other player the winner.
The game ends when one player removes the last penny from the final pile.

Objective:
Given these rules, how can players A and B strategize their moves to maximize their chances of winning? I am particularly interested in understanding the concept of subgame equilibrium in this context. Are there specific strategies or techniques that can be employed to predict the outcome of the game based on initial moves and how subgame equilibria might affect those strategies?
Here is a visual representation of the game dynamics: Game Chart.
I would appreciate any insights, strategies, or mathematical analyses that could help clarify the winning conditions, optimal moves, and the implications of subgame equilibrium in this game.

Can you provide a chart that is easier to read and higher resolution image? By the way since you have the whole chart, can't you just start from the leaves of the tree and identify winning nodes from the bottom to the top that way?

@BenjaminWang Done ! Updated the link

Is this not just a specific case of Nim?

@BenjaminWang it is. But it's subgame equilibrium is hard to find...

What does "equilibrium" mean in this context? This is a game with perfect information. Usually "equilibrium" is only meaningful with imperfect information games.

It seems like subgame equilibrium would be very close to perfect strategy, and as Benjamin Wang pointed out, your tree basically tells you perfect strategy. Can you maybe explain what you're trying to find in this context and where you're getting stuck?

This is standard multiheap nim with misere rules. The winning strategy is the same as normal multiheap nim (i.e. leave pile sizes whose combined XOR value is zero), except that if your move would leave an even number of size-1 piles, leave an odd number of size-1 piles instead. With only two piles this reduces to the simpler strategy of making the two piles equal size, except that if that would leave 1,1 you leave 0,1 (or 1,0) instead.
